# Magento same product with multiple source costs various vendors but with same sale price?

Tags: php, magento

In my magento shop, the same products will have a slightly different cost based on some cases but I sell the same price.

**Question:** how do i set up my product so it has multiple source costs?

**Idea Question:** Is there any way I can fill in the products cost after people placed an order, also including the amount and the provider's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is set up Tier Pricing and Customer Groups, so that you have a different price structure since thats what your wanting.  To add a price later would be maybe something something like using an observer class [Magento : how to change item price when adding it into the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270261/magento-how-to-change-item-price-when-adding-it-into-the-cart)

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but I don't mean this. The cost I mentioned is the price I bought it, or my provider's price. Such as a watch, I bought it as 1000CNY in September, and I bought another one in October is 950CNY. I always sell as USD 200$. How would I fill in the "cost" or "provider" in Magento backend?

Comment: I appriciate if you can answer me.

Comment: I get you, let me see if i can wrap my head around that portion and remember how i used to do that.  The first thing thats coming to mind is did you try putting it in as a different product?  Will that even be helpful?  What about if you dont make that 2nd product visible since its a duplicate?

Comment: Same sku, multiple cost, same product price, one final inventory count?  And is your version enterprise, to which you have a Gift Card feature which you might be able to leverage for this?  Also, heres a thing you might explore http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7432/set-multiple-costs-and-qty-for-products.

Comment: Thank you, Professor Brian Thomas. I checked my original platform and the data, which was developed by our own staff. A product(same price and same SKU), but the wholesale price is updating daily, and there are few providers in my local land. 100 sales as 200$ from PayPal, but the wholesale prices are all different. I don't have my own inventory in depot either. So when a buyer placed order, then I will check the price and select a provider, then when I deliveried the products, then I can fill in the wholesale price and provider name. I use Magento CE 1.9, is there other solution without ERP?

Comment: Yeah paul, its beyond my understanding of Magento.  maybe we can try editing your post to get some attention, mind if i edit your title to keep it like that for a while?  you can switch it back if it doesnt suit you?  By the way, this may be my fault that this post is going nowhere, because the question is written poorly.  What you need to be doing to get the correct answers it tapping into that audience.  Can you now take what you know, and what you did and totally revamp your OP?  add code example in there if applicable?