# Event observer not getting product details

Tags: php, magento, events, observers, magento-1.9.1

I have created a observer event like below inside my config.xml file

```
<events>          
              <sales_quote_add_item>
                  <observers>
                     <CustomModule_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>CustomModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>updatePrice</method>
                     </CustomModule_model_observer>
                 </observers>
              </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>
```

In my Model i have created Observer.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class CustomModule_Observer
{
    public function _construct()
      {
      }

    public function getNewPrice()
      {

        $newprice = "5";

        return $newprice;
      }

     public function updatePrice($observer)
     {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();// not getting any values how can i get this.
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = $this->getNewPrice();
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item->save();
      }
  }
```

Reference [Changing the price in quote while adding product to cart: magento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20715051/683395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this, and its working, it gives us the product id.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item){
   $productId = $item->getProductId();
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not get any value in `$product = $event->getProduct();` because this object is not set when add item event is dispatched.

Please check `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` class line number 939.

```
$item->setQuote($this);
    if (!$item->getId()) {
        $this->getItemsCollection()->addItem($item);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add_item', array('quote_item' => $item));
    }
```

Its only return quote_item object. If want products so you have to find some other way like :

```
 $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem(); // Which return quote item 
 $quote_item->getProduct();
```

I hope this is work for you Thanks.