# Change subtotal with given price & quantity (custom attribute)

Tags: magento, overwrite, magento-1.8, subtotal

My price is for example 10,00 €
this price is for 100 g
the customer can add any g in the quantity field for example 300

magento has now a subtotal of 3000, its ok but not for my needs here.

i need to do:
if price & quantity is set, get subtotal / price quantity, set new subtotal

where can i put my modifications for this?

Thank you very much!
Dennis

**Edit**
and the third try of observer (not working atm, no error, nothing happens):

```
    class Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
        }

        public function apply_quantity_order($observer)
        {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $pricequantity = $order->getPricequantity();

        if($pricequantity != ''){
            $old_sub_total = $order->getTotals();
            $new_sub_total = $old_sub_total / 100;
            $order->setTotals($new_sub_total);
        } else {}

        return $this;
        }
        public function apply_quantity_quote($observer)
        {
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $pricequantity = $quote->getPricequantity();

        if($pricequantity != ''){
            $old_sub_total = $quote->getTotals();
            $new_sub_total = $old_sub_total / 100;
            $quote->setTotals($new_sub_total);
        } else {}

        return $this;
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <xyzcatalog>
             <class>Xyz_Catalog_Model</class>
        </xyzcatalog>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
          <xyz_catalog_price_observer>
            <class>Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer</class>
            <method>apply_quantity_order</method>
          </xyz_catalog_price_observer>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_save_after>
      <sales_quote_save_after>
        <observers>
          <xyz_catalog_price_observer>
            <class>Xyz_Catalog_Model_Price_Observer</class>
            <method>apply_quantity_quote</method>
          </xyz_catalog_price_observer>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than overriding sub-total calculation function, I suggest to try events - sales_quote_save_after and sales_order_save_after.

You can get quote and sales in observer method by

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder() //for order
$observer->getEvent()->getQuote() //for quote
```

Then modify the subtotal accordingly.

Edit: It might be just hint how can you modify sub total.

Edit2: You have to add event observer in your config as shown:

```
<sales_order_save_after>
    <observers>
        <yourext>
            <class>yourext/observer</class>
            <method>observerMethod</method>
        </yourext>
    </observers>
</sales_order_save_after>
```

For detail, have look on [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

Comment: where can i work with this "Events", i am maybe able to get some code to work, i just dont know where the right place for it is. Thx

Comment: The exsample in the link worked. My try of my own code is for sure wrong at all :-) (Look my edit). I am unsure with the xml <tax>? And how to use Order and Quote the right way here. Maybe i am close and you can help me once more. Thank you very much.

Comment: ops, I am sorry about tax, in fact I copied that code. it should be `yourext` I make edit on my answer, let me edit your question. See KrishEdit1 part.

Comment: I am sorry, discard my edit. You have to add two `tax` can be replaced by anything like `ayourext` or anything. It is just id of event observer. You have to added two events `sales_order_save_after` and `sales_quote_save_after`.

Comment: i updated my code at the top. i think we get close, but getQuote dont work. Thx

Comment: I am sorry, I did another typo mistake, `getEvent()` is function so please do it like `$observer->getEvent()->getQuote()`. Notice (). I edited my answer too.

Comment: no error anymore, but my try to change the subtotals failed, just nothing happens. Do i use get und set the right way? Thank you, i learn much about magento again =)

Comment: Please debug your `apply_quantity_quote()` and `apply_quantity_order()` functions line by line. There are some mistake such as you have to call `save()` method after you make changes. Such as call `$order->save()` at very last line.

Comment: Also, updating sup-total is not that easy, you have to edit lot of other fields. See Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals() function for example

Comment: I think it is time that you accept my answer. Please click accept icon (right symbol).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @ [Programmatically add product to cart with price change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104482/programmatically-add-product-to-cart-with-price-change)

```
public function applyDiscount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }

    // calc special price
    $percentDiscount = 5;
    $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() -  $percentDiscount;

    // Make sure we don't have a negative
    if ($specialPrice > 0) {
        $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this dont work well anymore, will try it out tomorrow. Thx

Comment: You could also try giving the customer a discount on the total instead of on the price.. see http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total