# Programmatically Apply Multiple Shopping Cart Price Rules Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to figure out a way of applying multiple shopping cart price rules to a single cart in Magento.  The rules would be 'one-off' rules applicable to a unique cart for one customer.

I have no problem creating the rules using Allan's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798069/creating-a-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento-automatically), but I can only apply one coupon code at a time to a quote object:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
->getQuote()
->setCouponCode('foobar')
->collectTotals()
->save();
```

I could merge all of my custom price rules in to one rule, but I'm still left with the issue of blocking the customer from entering their own code on the front end.

The table `sales_flat_quote` in the database has a field `applied_rule_ids` which I'm guessing holds shopping cart rules triggered that are not applied as a result of a coupon code entered on the front end.  Is there a way piggy back on the this automatic process?

I'm trying to see if there's a way to do this gracefully without creating a custom totals collector and adding additional attributes to the quote and order objects.

Any ideas as to an attack route?

Comment: Take a look @ http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programming-magento/programmatically-create-apply-and-delete-shopping-cart-price-rule-in-magento/ - Programmatically create, apply and delete Shopping Cart Price Rule in Magento

Comment: Thanks, had already seen that one.  The issue is specifically the ability to apply multiple coupon codes (which isn't covered in the link above).

Comment: Have you figured this one out yet? I do not believe Magento has the capability to apply multiple rules to a cart.

Comment: @MB34 Went another route programmatically, but would still be interested in a solution

Comment: I'd like to know if you were successful at getting Magento to auto apply a rule like in the inchoo.net link provided by R.S above.